# Python quivalent for a C# Object

Tags: python, object

We have a python script which can interact with a couple of Bosch Rexroth servo drivers. We can succesfully read data from it's parameters but we cannot write to parameters. We use the Bosch Easy Automation Library (EAL.dll)

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("EAL")

import EAL  # imports EAL.dll
from EAL.EALConnection import *
from System import Console
from System.Threading import Thread
```

The very most propable cause is that we are using the `writeData()` method wrong. The drives should accept new parameters, we can do so in Indraworks. [Documentation](https://apps.boschrexroth.com/docs/oci/eal/html/75fb2cf5-0741-ef4c-7e4c-8582551d8baa.htm) dictates that the 'data' must an object type. Until so far everything has been a string. It is how we read data in, how we stuff it in JSON etc

This is the code we were using

```
    x = json.loads( message )

    servoid   =     x["servoid"]
    parameter =     x["parameter"]
    value     =     x["value"]

    #parameter = "P-0-4006.0.0"  # TEMPORAL OVERRIDE

    print("servoid: "   + servoid )
    print("parameter: " + parameter )
    print("value: "     + value )
    print()

    try:
        if servoid == "0":
            conn1.Parameter.Axes[0].WriteData( value, parameter )
        if servoid == "1":
            conn2.Parameter.Axes[0].WriteData( value, parameter )

        toWrite = True

    except EAL.Exceptions.EALException:
        print("The given data type and system type are not compatible.")
```

To solve the problem we tried hardcoding value as:

```
value = [0.0000, 0.0000, 3000.0000, 0.0000]
```

and

```
value = {0.0000, 0.0000, 3000.0000, 0.0000}
```

but they yield the same result. `The given data type and system type are not compatible.`

We have not tried to make an actual class and create such an object.

What is the python equivalent for?

```
C#:
void WriteData(
    Object data,
    string idn
)

Visual basic:
Sub WriteData ( 
    data As Object,
    idn As String
)

Visual C++:
void WriteData(
    Object^ data, 
    String^ idn
)
```

EDIT
In order to read the data we use the `ReadDataAsString()`. Needless to say, this returns a string.

The read data is captured like "0.0000 0.0000 3000.0000 0.0000" but this is heavily depended on which parameter you read. There is a also a parameter which returns 64 binary values like this.

```
print("reading value from axis 0")
value = conn1.Parameter.Axes[0].ReadDataAsString(parameter)
print("read value from axis 0: {}".format(value))
```

Comment: check what types the WriteData object accept, probably you IDE can give you hints of it

Comment: just (Function) WriteData: Any. I am using VSCode

Comment: I have been looking at the bosch site. In the example they can simply stuff an integer in `writeData()`. This parameter needs 4 values in an array

Comment: how do the parameters that you read look like?

Comment: I edited the question. Short anwser: a string of space-separated numbers

Comment: and if you give the value as your read it gives you an error?

Comment: Yes as a string it also tosses an error